# Making a single Google Calendar event that users can subscribe to via a link?

Tags: google-calendar

I'm planning an event using Google Calendar, but I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible. I'd like to:

1. Give users a link to the event, so they can add it to their own calendars (either Google Cal or iCalendar). Asking each person for their email address is not an option; I need to have a link that can be broadcasted.
2. Have the link be truly that: a link. I may need to update the event details, and I'd prefer if the changes get reflected on all guests' calendars, either automatically or via a new event invite that gets sent automatically. Simply having a one-time copy of the event on their calendar isn't sufficient.

I don't need RSVP features or anything beyond that, but if they're available with an approach that works for the above points it'd be nice to have. So far, I can't tell if what I want to do is possible, but I would appreciate any advice on this!